# TestDisk Ignore Aliases

Tags: linux, windows-8, testdisk

I'm trying to use TestDisk to take the contents of my old linux boot drive, and copy it to a storage drive (I am doing this from windows 8). I believe that TestDisk is getting into infinite loops due to aliases, is there a way to copy all the files in a directory while ignoring aliases in TestDisk?

Comment: Why would you want to copy the contents of /boot?

Comment: I just want to copy my desktop. It's formatted as a linux filesystem, so I need TestDisk to extract the files.

Comment: /boot does not have anything to do with your desktop. All your personal files are located in /home. Parts of /boot are generated at install time and there is no reason to copy them

Comment: Perhaps I'm using terminology wrong, but it's a physical hard drive from which I boot into linux

Comment: Yes, the terminology is wrong. How are you running testdisk? in a linux live-usb? in windows? Why testdisk and not just copy over the files?

Comment: I'm just running it in windows. The hard drive doesn't appear on my list of drives, which I assume is because it's not formatted as a windows storage drive, so I try to extract files with testdisk

Comment: Do you have a linux live-usb? That would be so much easier. Testdisk recovers partitions and other advanced operations that, it is probably not suited for the job. Also there must be many windows tools for this